# specify own delegate in class, have type checking in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, delegates, interface-builder, typechecking

I wrote an objective-C class that needs to notify another class, so i defined a protocol for a delegate:

```
@protocol glob_protocol <NSObject>
  @required
  - (IBAction) call:(int) val val2:(int) val2;
@end
```

In my class i have a member to store the delegate:

```
  IBOutlet id <glob_protocol> delegate;
```

When connecting the classes / instances in the Interface Builder there is no type checking now.  I can connect any class as a delegate.

Is there a way to enable type checking?  I'd like that only classes / instances that implement the protocol can be set as delegates.

Thanks for any hints,
Torsten.

EDIT:
I just checked in the Header files of UIKit to see if there are any additional infos or keywords but i did not find any.  I wonder where InterfaceBuilder got tthe information from what instances can be set as delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this usually works:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<glob_protocol>)inDelegate
{
  if (inDelegate) {
    assert([inDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(glob_protocol)]);
  }
  ...
}
```

although that's not at the level/phase you want, it works well because connections don't change often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help me.  In the code i (of course) check if the delegate is not nil and check if he conforms to the protocol before calling it.  I'm interested in letting the InterfaceBuilder check if an instance can be set as delegate.

Comment: @Torsten I understood the problem and what you wanted. I answered with the nearest alternative I know of because there is currently no support/hack for what you want (afaik).

Comment: Ok, thanks then.  If it is not possible to have checking enabled in InterfaceBuilder then i'll stick with what i have now and just be careful in assigning the delegates.